# How to analyse in detail who clicked the advertisement?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads

Using Facebook Ads we can segment things like "parents with kids from 6-8 who live in Antarctica and like beaches". However, let's say we don't segment our potential clients (because we don't know who they are). Let's say eight potential clients clicked on the advertisement and one client bought a product.

Is it possible to analyse them or cross the common data?

In other words, is it possible to know data like the eight potential clients like soccer or have kids?

Or only is possible to know their age and country?